# Does the configuration of a confined layer change the storage?

Tags: hydrology, groundwater

I have a confined aquifer of sand. I will temporarily drain the aquifer, remove the top one meter of the aquifer and then replace that with a layer of gravel. After that I will restore the layer (and the aquitard above it). After that, it is a confined layer again.

Is the storage of the aquifer different with the small layer of gravel?

Comment: It all depends on the pore space in each unit volume of sand or gravel.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal conditions a layer of gravel has more hydraulic conductivity in comparison to sand. Check this [table with a hydraulic conductivity k per soiltype](http://structx.com/Soil_Properties_007.html)

The storage in the aquifer with gravel will be larger than in sand if the same thickness is used. Otherwise you should take the thickness into account as well (= Transmissivity: kD).